# Trying to count the number of data stored - Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba

So, I've created a multi-tab on my framework where input data will be saved and shown on those tabs as either pending or solved issues.

I wrote a code to also count how many issues there are depending on the priority.
The issue I'm facing here is that I assigned `i`, `j` and `k` as Long but I'm currently getting the error code `13`, saying there is a *Mismatch of Types*.

Could anyone please provide some guidance on this please?

```
Private Sub MultiPage_Change()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
        
    If MultiPage.Value = 0 Then
        i = [CountIf (Pending Complaints!G:G, "High")]
        j = [Countif(Pending Complaints!G:G, "Medium")]
        k = [Countif(Pending Complaints!G:G, "Low")]

        With frmComplaint       
            .frmSummary.Caption = "Pending Complaints Summary"
            .LbHigh.Caption = i
            .LbMedium.Caption = j
            .LbLow.Caption = k
            .LbOverall.Caption = i + j + k
        End With
    Else
        i = [Countif(Resolved Complaints!G:G, "High")]
        j = [Countif(Resolved Complaints!G:G, "Medium")]
        k = [Countif(Resolved Complaints!G:G, "Low")]
        
        With frmComplaint
            .frmSummary.Caption = "Resolved Complaints Summary"
            .LbHigh.Caption = i
            .LbMedium.Caption = j
            .LbLow.Caption = k
            .LbOverall.Caption = i + j + k
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate your error. Which line is the error thrown on?

Comment: Hi Sam, the error occurred from line 7, where it says i = [Countif...].

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues:

1. There is a space infront of the parenthesis that should not be there:
   `i = [CountIf (Pending Complaints!G:G, "High")]` must be
   `i = [CountIf(Pending Complaints!G:G, "High")]`
2. If there is a space in your sheet name `Pending Complaints` it needs to be in apostrophes:

   Change `i = [CountIf(Pending Complaints!G:G, "High")]` into
   `i = [CountIf('Pending Complaints'!G:G, "High")]`

   This needs to be changed in the other lines too.

Comment: I tested with implicit reference to the sheet. This answer is more thorough and correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your assignment.

`i = [CountIf (Pending Complaints!G:G, "High")]` has a space between `CountIf` and `(Pending...`

Remove the space and your error will disappear.

Like so:

`i = [CountIf(Pending Complaints!G:G, "High")]`

**Note:** the rest of your assignment's are written correctly in that regard.